# how to add custom properties metadata to the pdf using apache fop

Tags: java, pdf, metadata, apache-fop

I am using apache FOP to create PDF files and need to add specific metadata to the PDF. In adobe reader it is called "custom properties" and it contains name and value.
I can add simple metadata like this:

```
out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
foUserAgent.setKeywords("some keywords");
```

But I need to add customised metadata with name and value. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're lucky with the [XMP support in FOP 1.1](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/metadata.html)? Try with some keys that you find in the [XMP specification](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xmp/sdk/XMPspecification.pdf).